# Android : Google Photos like Grid View with Zoom Functionality

Tags: android, material-design, android-recyclerview

I am using Recycle view and GridLayoutManager to display images in a grid.I would like to add functionality like Google photos where the Grid will be auto arranged and resizes images in Gridview when user pinch zooms.I am looking for sample code reference or procedure how to achieve it. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible but the easiest way would be to create an ontouchlistener with pinch to zoom in the onBindViewHolder, you should also add `android:clipToPadding="false"` on the ImageView and all its parents & `android:clipChildren="false"` on all the parents.

Answer (score 0):

i recomended this library to pinchzoon in your item recyclerview 
https://github.com/imablanco/Zoomy

you just need called like this in your onBindViewHolder

```
val builder = Zoomy.Builder(context as MainPrivateActivity)
        .target(holder.itemView)
        .interpolator(OvershootInterpolator())
        .tapListener { v ->
                listener.onItemClick(it)

        }
        .doubleTapListener { v ->
            //listener.onItemLike(v, position)
        }
    builder.register()
```